# How do I gate a z0103ma triac using logic level output?

Tags: arduino, triac

I'm trying to switch an el wire segment on and off by using a z0103ma triac. I have the AC current connected across pins 1 and 3, and when the gate is closed, the ac current is interrupted, but once I connect the gate to a digital output pin on my arduino, the gate is open and current flows, regardless of what voltage (0 or 5 volts) I put onto the gate.

Am I doing something wrong? What signal do I need to send to the gate to open and close the triac?

Comment: How are you referencing the Arduino to the line voltage?

Comment: Dont electrocute yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The [MOC3041](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/MO/MOC3041M.pdf) is indeed a suitable optocoupler to use -- figure 15 in the datasheet (reproduced below) is your reference, by the way.  You don't need a DIAC with an optoTRIAC/TRIAC combo, and the MOC3041 is in a 6 pin DIP -- pins 1/2 are the LED and 4/6 are the optoTRIAC.

[image: Figure 15 from the MOC3041 D/S]

Answer (score 0):

In the following schematic; remove the potentiometer and and replace the DIAC with a TRIAC optocoupler. Operate the LED in the optocoupler with the Arduino like an ON/OFF switch.

[image]

Here is an example of what you would be looking for. Pin 3 and 4 go instead of the DIAC. Pin 1 and 2 are an LED that with the help of a resistor can be turned on and off with the Arduino. This is the safe way to do this because the Arduino is fully isolated from mains voltage. 
[image]

Comment: The MOC3041 doesn't need a DIAC, nor is the pinout you give for it correct.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sorry, i was at the mercy of the illustration. I was going more for a picture of a TRIAC optocoupler than an actual part.